# Store Locator in google maps, input zip code and display markers on map and sidebar

Tags: html, google-maps, autocomplete, infowindow, search-box

I'm close to finishing this but I'm having a trouble with the Search box of gmaps.
The concept of the project is to type in a zip code(in my example a fixed one, 15124) and display on the map a number of markers(representing the stores in that area) and in a sidebar their names.
 The **only problem** I am facing is the auto-complete/getPlaces property that the search-box has. 
How do I get rid of this property? 
I just want a plain input text so that i can write the z.c. and then take that and compare it to see if it's true.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 

<title>Store Locate</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&libraries=places"></script> 


  #pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 400px;
  }

  #pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  .pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
  }

  #type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

  #type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  var side_bar_html = "";
  // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
  var gmarkers = []; 
  var marker;
  var map = null;
  var t=1;

function initialize() {
// create the map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 11,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.9833333, 23.7333333),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions:{style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });


 initSearchBox(map, 'pac-input');
}//----------------INIT END--------------------


 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
 { 
 size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
 }); 

 // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");

}

function initSearchBox(map, controlId) {
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

// [START region_getplaces]
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
// pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    //get first place
    var place = places[0];


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
 { 
  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
  content : place.info
 }); 

// Add markers to the map
// Set up the markers with info windows 
// add the points 

if ((document.getElementById(controlId).value) == ("Marousi, 15124, Vorios Tomeas Athinon, Greece" ||(document.getElementById(controlId).value) == 15124) && t==1){  

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0397739,23.8004445);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Relay Marketing","<b>Relay Marketing Services</b> <br>Vlahernon 10,15124,Marousi<br>211 411 2311")

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0409333,23.7954601);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Nespresso S.A.","<b>Nespresso S.A.</b><br>Agiou Thoma 27,15124,Marousi")

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0473031,23.8053483);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Regency Entertainment","<b>Regency Entertainment</b><br>Agiou Konstantinou 49,15124,Marousi <br>210 614 9800")

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.050986,23.8084322);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Just4U","<b>Just4U</b> <br>Dimitriou Gounari 84, 15124, Marousi<br>210 614 1923")

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0400533,23.8011982);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Ekka Cars S.A.","<b>Ekka</b> <br>Leoforos Kifisias 79,15124,Marousi<br>210 349 8000")

// put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
t -=1;//This is so if you search again, it doesn't display again in sidebar
}

    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
});
}

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    //zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

 // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
 gmarkers.push(marker);
 // add a line to the side_bar html
 side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script> 
</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" > 
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Ταχυδρομικός κωδικός">
<table border="1"> 
  <tr> 
    <td> 
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div> 
    </td> 
    <td valign="top" style="width:160px; text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;"> 

       <div id="side_bar"></div> <hr/>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
 </table>  
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to add search box**

1 Ensure [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) is loaded, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

> Note: To use the functionality contained within this library, you must
>   first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap
>   URL: `libraries=places`

2. Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

HTML:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

JavaScript:

```
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

3 Initialize Search Box control:

```
function initSearchBox(map,controlId) {
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //get first place
        var place = places[0];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);


    });
}
```

**Example**

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714364, -74.005972),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


    var locations = [
        ['New York', 40.714364, -74.005972, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']
    ];


  
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });


    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: locations[i][3]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        markers.push(marker);
    }

    initSearchBox(map, 'pac-input');


}


function initSearchBox(map, controlId) {
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //get first place
        var place = places[0];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location,
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png'
        });

        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);


    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}

.controls {
     margin-top: 16px;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     height: 32px;
     outline: none;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: Roboto;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin-left: 12px;
     padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
     border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
     font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #4d90fe;
     padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
     font-family: Roboto;
     font-size: 13px;
     font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this example on Google website, it's an complete HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

    </style>
    <title>Places search box</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope it will be useful...

**Source : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox**

Comment: I am aware of this and what I'm trying is to combine these two but I can't.
As I'm new to this I can't alter/fuse the code of the search-box with the clickable sidebar. Thanks for your time.